# What is this extra lead in my monitor cable?

Tags: commodore-64, audio, commodore

I have a breadbox Commodore 64 with a Commodore 1702 monitor.

My monitor has three RCA-style inputs on the back:

- Audio (White)
- Luma (Yellow)
- Chroma (Red)

I purchased a cable which claims to be an original Commodore 64 monitor cable, but I believe it must have been made for a later model of the monitor (or perhaps for a different Commodore computer altogether) because it has four leads: White, Black, Red, and Blue. It's possible that the white may have originally been yellow, because all of the colors are quite faded. The cable sheath is light grey (but may have originally been white).

Through trial and error, I've discovered the red lead carries the Luma signal and the blue lead carries the Chroma signal.

Are the black and white cables both audio? Can I use an [RCA Y-splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014QK4R44) to merge them? Can I connect them directly into a standalone speaker set (with the standard white-red/left-right RCA-style female connectors)?

Comment: The SID pinout I found — http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/~schepers/MJK/pics/6581.gif — shows only one 'audio out'. So I'm confident the machine is fully internally mono, making two audio outputs unlikely.

Comment: @Tommy is it possible that the c128 or perhaps the pet or amiga used sound chips with two channels?

Comment: i just found [these pictures of a 1084ST monitor](http://www.bigbookofamigahardware.com/bboah/product.aspx?id=850) -- it looks like they have two audio inputs.

Comment: Various pinouts suggest the extra cable is either composite video out, or audio in.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow definitely possible. I've gone the traal route in producing an answer based on the pinout, but he's right that it could be audio in, as the SID is designed to be able to work in series with other audio. I think composite out is more likely though, as per the quantity of Apple ][ monitors.

Comment: There are usually three video channels - is the black lead actually a video channel?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 i tried plugging it into the luma receiver and just got a black screen. same with the white lead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Do over answer]

Based on your clue that an Atari monitor has matching coloured inputs I looked up the Atari 8-bit video connector, compared to the C64:

[image]

It is likely you have an Atari lead rather than a Commodore one. So your four signals are intended to be (1) luminance; (2) audio; (3) composite video; (4) chroma where available.

Plugging that cable into a C64 will give you luminance, audio out and composite video on the same outputs as they would have been on an Atari. But the connection that's offered for chroma output will actually function as an audio in.

Composite video should be usable as luminance because that was a key concern affecting its original design — it's the same issue as backwards compatibility with black and white sets.

Therefore of your two spare ends, one is audio out and one is audio in.

Comment: hello tommy, i get a black screen if i put the black or white cables into luma. if i put the blue cable into luma, i get a grayscale picture.

Comment: i just found [these pictures of a 1084ST monitor](http://www.bigbookofamigahardware.com/bboah/product.aspx?id=850) and it looks like they accept audio left/right channels. and the colors seem to match up with my cable. i'm confused, though, because (as you said) the SID only has one audio output.

Comment: also if i plug the black cable into the audio pin, i get most of the audio... but it's much quieter than expected and interspersed with loud popping (these pops are on-beat with the music). if i use the white cable, i get slightly different pops (but again, on-beat with the music) and none of the melodic parts are audible anymore.

Comment: I think you've cracked it. You've got an Atari cable. I'll update the answer.

Comment: i think you mean "amiga", not "atari", right? and i think it is left/right (not in/out), based on the labels in the picture. i'm still confused, though, because if the SID only has one output, why am i hearing differences between the black and white cables?

Comment: (marked as community wiki, since we're solving this as a team); I'm looking at the 8-bit Atari pinouts, as per the image [now] included. The Commodore and Atari have virtually the same connector. Whoever originally bought the cable probably long ago forgot that it said Commodore/Atari on the box? The only round video connector I can find evidence of on an ST (a computer I've never seen in real life) has 14 pins.

Comment: okay, so it seems like white/black was *meant* to connect to audio left/right on an atari, but it's *actually* connecting to audio in/out on my c64?
and perhaps the Commodore 1084ST monitor was designed to be compatible with the Atari ST, explaining why it has left/right inputs?

Comment: and i have the composite video signal going into the chroma input on my monitor? i definitely need to get a new cable.

Comment: @Tommy Did you mean to make this community wiki?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. It definitely looks like you'd do better with an 8-pin cable, for real S-Video, if you can obtain one.

Comment: The key thing is if the DIN connector at the computer end has 5 pins instead of 8 then it's an 8-bit Atari/C64 cable.  An 8 pin cable won't work in a Atari, and 5 pin C64 cables didn't support separate chroma and so only had two RCA jacks, one for composite video the other for audio.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, since Woodrow ended up doing a lot of the work himself in spotting the Atari monitor inputs. So it was a team effort.

Comment: @RossRidge yup, it has 5 pins. thanks for the tip, i'll use that when buying a new cable.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I remember having using one of those 5-pin Atari/C64 video cables (still have it in fact) and as I recall the quality wasn't noticeably different between it and a official 8-pin Commodore cable. The key thing is that there's still a separate luminance pin on the 5-pin connector and separating that from the chroma is what gets you most of the improvement.

Comment: Perhaps the cable was built to support the Commodore's audio input, though I have no idea whether anything actually used that.  It might have been helpful for some audio expansion devices to allow their output to be combined with the C64's main audio, though I have no idea how well that would work.

Comment: The Atari 800 and 800XL cable is wired the same as the Commodore VIC-20 cable.